# printing the whole array in powerbuilder textboxes

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm learning PowerBuilder at the moment. I want to create an array and simply print(show) it to see if and how it is going to work.
I tried this code:

```
decimal {2} arr[2, 2]
arr[1, 1] = 10
arr[1, 2] = 20
arr[2, 1] = 30
arr[2, 2] = 40

sle_1.text = string(arr[1, 1])
sle_2.text = string(arr[1, 2])
sle_3.text = string(arr[2, 1])
sle_4.text = string(arr[2, 2])
```

and saw all the elements in 4 different textboxes, which is ok. But a better practice is to see it as a whole entity. For that; I tried different forms:

```
sle_1.text = string(arr)
```

- 

```
sle_1.text = string(arr[])
```

- 

```
sle_1.text = string(arr[:])
```

- 

```
sle_1.text = string(arr[*])
```

but some of them raised errors and some others seem to show the memory address of the array not the elements of it.

Any help in learning this weird non-rich-documented language will be appreciated.

p.s.
Isn't there a way for printing the result of a peace of code in PowerBuilder like the ones that are in, python or c for example; I mean not needing to necessarily create a textbox to see the result of the code - Somewhere like a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The single line edit control will only display strings in it's text property.  If you just wnat to see the value in your array at runtime you can put a breakpoint in your code, run it in the debugger, then examine the values during your debug session.  If you want to display them then you either can concantenate the values into a single string (something like string(arr[1,1]) + ' ' + string(arr{1,2]) + ' ' + string(arr[2,1]) + ' ' + string(arr[2,2]) ) or put four separate single line edit controls on your form and place the value of each element into the text property.

Comment: Thank you. What about the other question? Seeing the output of the code in a terminal-like window; rather than being forced to define a datawindow to see the results?

Comment: You can run in the debugger and set watchpoints to view various things.